# Mysql Exception in JAVA project

Tags: java, mysql, exception

In a simple java application with jdbc and mysql only I am getting error :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
```

Threading is used to open and close connection to Mysql

I have tried increasing the max_connection variable of MySQL but it only delays the exception as it will again arise if the number of threads are increased

Please provide root cause and resolution.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Connection1 extends Thread{
public java.sql.Connection con = null;

public Connection1() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        for(int i=0;i<500;i++) {
            new Thread(new Connection1().new  StartTester(i)).start();
        }
    }

    public void looper() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            new Thread(this.new  StartTester(i)).start();
        }
    }

    public void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","esignal");
        System.out.println("con success "+con);
        con.close();
        System.out.println("con Closed "+con);
    }

    class StartTester implements Runnable {

        public StartTester(int count) {
            System.out.println("Thread count "+count);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                connect();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: putting some **code** in the question may solve the problem

Comment: try using some db pooling e.g. apache dbcp

Comment: Post you code snippet.

Comment: have a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) page.

Comment: Please look in the below code:

Comment: Are you closing older connection that are remain idle or useless ?

Comment: public void looper() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
 {
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
   new Thread(this.new  StartTester(i)).start();
  }
 }
 public void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
 {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","pwd");
        System.out.println("con success "+con);
        con.close();
        System.out.println("con Closed "+con);
 }

Comment: I am closing all the connections

Comment: @user3713816, put your code on question, not in comment. Try to use conection pooling.

Comment: @ScaryWombat i AM NOT USING Tomcat server for this ..so can should it be useful to use Apache dbcp?

Comment: sorry I am not sure.  Also maybe you should put the `close` into a finally block in case of an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are spawning too many `Threads` (500) and there are limited number (say 20) of connection available on `MySQL`. When you try to create DB connection, it will take sometime. But threads will start very quickly. So almost all the threads are trying to connect to DB simultaneously but only 20 (or little more then 20) will get the connection and reset will throw the `Exception` that you have mentioned.

- You should use connectionPool to manage connection properly.
- Otherwise have a look at following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2313262/2421561). It will tell you how to handle `Connections` properly.

I would also recommend you to use [ExecutionService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115940/how-to-use-executorservice-of-java-concurrent-programming) to limit to number of thread and it is a cleaner approach (this is what I do). You should use create only 20 active (or whatever max connection count) threads and reset in ready to run mode. Hence recommending [ExecutionService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115940/how-to-use-executorservice-of-java-concurrent-programming) (Easiest to use).

My sample solution will be (you need to do proper implementation of `connect()` method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2313262/2421561):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Connection1 extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
    SQLException {
        // Number of max DB connection allowed
        int poolSize = 20;

        ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
        List<Future<String>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread count " + i);
            Callable<String> worker = new StartTester();
            Future<String> future = execService.submit(worker);
            futureList.add(future);
        }
    }
}

class StartTester implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() {
        try {
            connect();
            return "SUCCESS";
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "FAILURE";
    }

    public void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
                "root", "esignal");
        System.out.println("con success " + con);
        con.close();
        System.out.println("con Closed " + con);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: how can I work a resolution around this problem as I am not able to properly use ExecutionService

Comment: by limiting the threads I can reolve this standalone application

Comment: but what can I do If this is being handled by a TOMCAT server which handles the thread generation and even after putting the thread to close for more than an hour this exception is still there

Comment: For this you need to configure `context.xml` file present in `TOMCAT` directory. In this file you can specify all the properties related to connection pooling and also the `ConnectionPool` driver. I am using `tomcat-jdbc` and implementation similar to what I have provided. It is working fine for more the 6 months now.

Comment: These links might be helpful: [Link1](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/04/19/database-connection-pooling-with-tomcat.html) and [link2](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:-

1. Check the opened connections in database.
2. Check if your application is opening too many connections and not closing them.

Comment: All the connections are closed properly after being opened

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'synchronised' keyword to the methods that open and close connections

Comment: can't use synchronized as it will surely resolve the problem but will affect performance in production envoirment

Answer (score 0):

Like Dennis said you should check if your application keep opening connections.
If this is not the case then you should check how many connections your Database can handle (look in your DB configuration).

I do not know right now how many connections are established before you run your application. Is your Database productive or do you have a private database which run local?

If there are other applications or useres that use your database it is possible that connections to your DB has reached the maximum or you have not enough RAM. If you do not have enough RAM it is possible that mysql do not open more connections.

Comment: max_connections = 100

Comment: Mysql is running locally

Comment: RAM is 8 GB so connection opening is not a problem

Comment: and like you wrote you open 500 Threads that open a connection

Comment: I tried increasing the max_connections value but it would only delay the exception as it would again occur once the threads cross the limit

Comment: This only answers the cause but this exception would again reoccur as increasing the max_connection is temporary solution . Please assume the thread being generated is not limited

Comment: use a limiter in your code for how many connections can be established. We have now gave you all answers you nee do get a solution, if now you do not know how you get your problem solved then we can not help you anymore.

Comment: limiter will work for standalone application but what can I do If this is being handled by a TOMCAT server which handles the thread generation and even after putting the thread to close for more than an hour this exception is still there